# How can I hold a frame for a few seconds in a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

It's hard to describe it, but what I want to do is I have a video and at some point in the video I want to take the current frame, play it for some time like 5 seconds (i.e. displaying the last frame, a static image) and continue with the video.

How can I do this easily in Linux, preferably Ubuntu? If there's no easy way I may accept a Windows solution.

The reason I want to do it is because I have audio that is slightly longer than video and don't fit that well so I want to "extend" the video in appropriate places.

Comment: Do you want to make a video with still picture or just stop a video for some time during playback?

Comment: Stop a video for some time during playback i.e. I don't want a custom image. Something as if somebody clicked 'pause' on the video and it played like that for a few seconds, before being resumed.

Comment: See [ffmpeg pause video every 10 seconds for 3 seconds](https://superuser.com/a/1071524/110524) and [Add pauses in a video file with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/1186946/110524).

Answer (score 0):

it is not perfect but it can be done with vlc playlist. I don't know if such a list can be done with vlc GUI, since I changed a playlist by editing it by hand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
  <title>Playlist</title>
  <trackList>
    <track>
      <location>file:///somefile.mpg</location>
      <duration>4000</duration>
      <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
        <vlc:option>start-time=2</vlc:option>
        <vlc:option>stop-time=6</vlc:option>
      </extension>
    </track>
    <track>
      <location>vlc://pause:4</location>
      <duration>4000</duration>
      <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
      </extension>
    </track>
    <track>
      <location>file:///somefile.mpg</location>
      <duration>4000</duration>
      <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:id>2</vlc:id>
        <vlc:option>start-time=6</vlc:option>
        <vlc:option>stop-time=10</vlc:option>
      </extension>
    </track>
  </trackList>
  <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
    <vlc:item tid="0"/>
  </extension>
</playlist>
```

As you can see in the file there are three entries in the playlist. The video is first played seconds 2-6. Then player pauses for 4 seconds (`vlc://pause:4`), and then it plays seconds 6-10. I tried it but after pause it jumps a bit and plays some video from before the pause. Maybe that happens only with me or with tested video. However, no pause indication or anything like that appears on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, but that would require me to record the video as it plays, right (see my edit)? I mean it modifies only its playback in VLC, but I want to modify the video itself, so that I can send someone the file and it plays the same. Are you aware of any video editor (can be proprietary) that can do it on Linux or Windows?

Comment: I think that requires more effort, because you would like to pause video only and leave the sound playing. And after the pause ends you have even more complicated scenario, when you want to play audio ahead of video. I am not aware of any program that would beable to do that, except if you use video editing SW and do all the stuff by hand.